# Excel: Find words of certain length in string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have this file where I want to make a conditional check for any cell that contains the letter combination "_SOL", or where the string is followed by any numeric character like "_SOL1524", and stop looking after that. So I don't want matches for "_SOLUTION" or "_SOLothercharactersthannumeric".

So when I use the following formula, I also get results for words like "_SOLUTION":

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("_SOL",A1))=TRUE,"Yay","")
```

How can I avoid this, and only get matches if the match is "_SOL" or "_SOLnumericvalue" (one numeric character)

**Clarification:** The whole strings may be "Blabla_SOL_BLABLA", "Blabla_SOLUTION_BLABLA" or "Blabla_SOL1524_BLABLA"

Comment: By "and stop looking after that", do you mean "ends in '_SOL'"?

Comment: Please include samples of these file names

Comment: If you are checking if the cell contents end in "_SOL", then `=IF(RIGHT(A1,4)="_SOL","Yay","")` should work for you.

Comment: @Chronocidal no, not neccesarily. These are in the mid of the text string. So either for example "Blabla_SOL_BLABLA" or "Blabla_SOLUTION_BLABLA" or "Blabla_SOL1524_BLABLA".

Comment: @Applecore unfortunately they do not end in it.

Comment: What is the terminating character going to be? Is it always "_"?

Comment: When its always `_SOL_`your are searching for, why dont you look for that isntead?

Comment: @Applecore before the word yes, but after, it can be anything (whomever is behind my data is not very consistent in the naming conventions, and I won't be able to change that behavior). So far though, it does seem like the matches I want actually are the ones that are either `_SOL_` or `_SOL` with numeric values after the three letters SOL, like `_SOL1524`, and that I don't want matches that has other than numeric values after it). Maybe it's possible to specify numeric follow up? I updated the question to include numerics

Comment: And can this numeric part be of any length?

Comment: @JvdV yes, so the check should preferably only be for 1 numeric character. See the solution from SJR below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this, which will check if the character after "_SOL" is numeric.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("_SOL",A1)+4,1))),"Yay","")
```

Or, as per OP's request and suggestion, to include the possibility of an underscore after "SOL"

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("_SOL",A1)+4,1))),ISNUMBER(FIND("_SOL_",A1))),"Yay","")
```

Comment: Might want to also add an `OR` for when it's followed by an underscore?

Comment: @SJR nice! I added an `OR` condition and ended up with this, which works perfectly: `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("_SOL",A1)+4,1)))=TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND("_SOL_",A1))=TRUE),"Yay","")`. Feel free to update the answer with it. I marked it as the solution as it got me to where I needed to be.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit. Thanks for accepting - you can post your own adaptation as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way to check if your string contains `SOL` followed by either nothing or any numeric value up to any characters after `SOL`:

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","1</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring-after(.,'SOL')*0=0]")>0),"Yey","Nay")
```

Just to use in an unfortunate event where you would encounter `SOL1TEXT` for example. Or, maybe saver (in case you have text like `AEROSOL`):

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')='SOL']")>0),"Yey","Nay")
```

And to prevent that you have text like `123SOL123` you could even do:

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","1</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'SOL') and substring(., 4)*0=0]")>0),"Yey","Nay")
```

Comment: Really good! I'm still just getting into reading XML formulas, so I'm going with SJR's solution for now. Upvoted though. I'm sure it is good for anyone reaching this via search! Thanks (:

Comment: It's not a problem at all @Strechingmycompetence. SJR's formula is perfectly fine (you should also upvote that if it's been helpfull). Just wanted to give you the option. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) if these formulas interest you.